# Using Twit to post a video with a bot

Tags: node.js, twitter, sttwitterapi

```
function fridayNight(){
const videoPath = "C:\\GitHub\\DivasLive\\DivasLive\\nsync.mp4";
console.log("It's Friday night and I just Got Paid!");

var b64content = fs.readFileSync(videoPath, { encoding: 'base64' });
var mediaType = MIM.getMIMEType(videoPath);

 T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content, media_type: mediaType }, function (err, data, 
 response) 
 {
 if(err) 
 {
  console.log(err);
 } else 
 { 

 console.log(data);
 var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string
 var params = { status: "Just got paid!", media_id: [mediaIdStr] };

 T.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) 
  {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
  });
   };
 });
};
```

I keep getting a 400: Media type unrecognized, but I'm trying to explicitly define it in line 88. Here's the full gist as well. https://gist.github.com/MetzinAround/25b5771564aa7de183391398db52dbef

Answer (score 0):

For video and GIFs, you need to use the chunked media upload method - you cannot do it in a "single shot", it has multiple stages (INIT, APPEND, FINALIZE), [per the Twitter docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload).

> Please note that to upload videos or GIFs (tweet_video, amplify_video, and tweet_gif), you need to use the chunked upload end-point.

It turns out that the `twit` module has a helper method for doing this, `postMediaChunked` - this also saves you having to tell Twitter the mime type of the data, which means you can remove the import of the `mim` module.

Here's a minimal example of just doing the media part - you just need to extract the `media_id_string` and use that in the `statuses/update` call:

```js
// Create an Twitter object to connect to Twitter API
const Twit = require('twit')

// Making a Twit object for connection to the API
const T = new Twit(config)

var filePath = '/Users/myuser/Downloads/robot.mp4'
T.postMediaChunked({
  file_path: filePath
}, function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

output:

```
{
  media_id: 1379414276864151600,
  media_id_string: '1379414276864151557',
  media_key: '7_1379414276864151557',
  size: 924669,
  expires_after_secs: 86400,
  processing_info: { state: 'pending', check_after_secs: 1 }
}
```

(note that, in JavaScript, you should always use the string versions of Twitter IDs - as you can see here, the numeric version in `media_id` does not match `media_id_string`, as JavaScript cannot properly handle long integers, and has mangled the numeric value)

Comment: Am I understanding that Data is an object and media_id_string is a property of that object? IF I need to call Media_id_string later, do I do that with data.media_id_string?

Comment: yes, that should do it. Data is a JSON response from the API.